# Branding / white labelling Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureportal, branding, white-labelling

We'd like to use the Logic App UI/engine in the Azure Portal and give it to customers who have some development experience, so they are able to hook into our application to customise some calculations.

Is it possible to

a) Brand Azure Logic App/Portal resources with a company label etc or
b) Provide some other mechanism of creating Logic Apps (desktop, web UI) that uses Azure Logic Apps underneath

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that you set up some custom connectors into your application so that your customers can set up their own logic apps in their own subscriptions.

[Here's some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/)

If you had your customers using your logic apps, rebranded in some way, they would have access to each others cached credentials through saved connections which would be undesirable in many cases.